# jQuery question: How do I clean this code to be more effeciant, or is there a way to loop this?

Tags: jquery, loops, digit

This is my code, and it keeps repeating until :eq(15). I'm new to jQuery and JavaScript in general and I doubt that I'm doing this correctly. Can anyone help me with cleaning this code up into a loop maybe? I basically need this script to increase :eq(0) by 1 until 15.

```
var $titleMarquee = '<marquee scrollamount="5" direction="left" width="233" align="left" behavior="alternate" loop="1"><span>';

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(0)").mouseenter(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(0) .article-title a span').replaceWith($titleMarquee+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(0) .article-title a').text()+'</span></marquee>');});

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(0)").mouseleave(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(0) .article-title a marquee').replaceWith('<span>'+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(0) .article-title a').text()+'</span>');});  

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(1)").mouseenter(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(1) .article-title a span').replaceWith($titleMarquee+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(1) .article-title a').text()+'</span></marquee>');});

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(1)").mouseleave(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(1) .article-title a marquee').replaceWith('<span>'+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(1) .article-title a').text()+'</span>');});  

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(2)").mouseenter(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(2) .article-title a span').replaceWith($titleMarquee+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(2) .article-title a').text()+'</span></marquee>');});

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(2)").mouseleave(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(2) .article-title a marquee').replaceWith('<span>'+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(2) .article-title a').text()+'</span>');});  

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(3)").mouseenter(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(3) .article-title a span').replaceWith($titleMarquee+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(3) .article-title a').text()+'</span></marquee>');});

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(3)").mouseleave(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(3) .article-title a marquee').replaceWith('<span>'+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(3) .article-title a').text()+'</span>');});

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(4)").mouseenter(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(4) .article-title a span').replaceWith($titleMarquee+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(4) .article-title a').text()+'</span></marquee>');});

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(4)").mouseleave(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(4) .article-title a marquee').replaceWith('<span>'+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(4) .article-title a').text()+'</span>');});

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(5)").mouseenter(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(5) .article-title a span').replaceWith($titleMarquee+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(5) .article-title a').text()+'</span></marquee>');});

$("ul.side-block-content li:eq(5)").mouseleave(function(){$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(5) .article-title a marquee').replaceWith('<span>'+$('ul.side-block-content li:eq(5) .article-title a').text()+'</span>');});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give some HTML to work with?

Comment: `</marquee>`. You sir are the _devil_.

Comment: I thought <marquee> was deprecated long time ago.

Comment: @Krule: I don't think `marquee` was ever in any actual specification. It doesn't appear in the HTML [2.0](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1866), [3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html32), or [4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) specs (and obviously not in HTML5).

Comment: Really?! All of these great answers and none were accepted?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
    $("ul.side-block-content li:eq(" + i + ")").mouseenter(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.filter('.article-title a span').replaceWith(
        $titleMarquee + $this.filter('.article-title a').text() + '</span></marquee>');
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        var $this = $(this)
        $this.filter('.article-title a marquee').replaceWith('<span>' + $this.filter('.article-title a').text() + '</span>');
    });
}
```

P.S. I'm not sure this will work - need to see your HTML. (Don't know what is in $titleMarquee, and why there is no opening `<span>` in first replace)

Comment: *"P.S. Some time later I'll post the whole code"* Um, okay. So basically you're just trying to make sure you've got the first answer? Because what you've left out is ***central*** to answering the question.

Comment: That was really quick, thanks! The $titleMarquee is this: var $titleMarquee = '<marquee scrollamount="5" direction="left" width="233" align="left" behavior="alternate" loop="1"><span>'; Am I supposed to replace $this with something? or use that as written because it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: @Innuendo: You don't really want to be creating a global variable called `$this`, do you?

Comment: I got it to work! Thank you everyone who answered my question.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: I mostly always create $this variable. But yes, in this example, it's better to create variables like you did in your answer

Comment: @Innuendo: My problem wasn't with the name (I use that name too), it was with the fact you were making it a *global*. (You need a `var`.)

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Ooooh, sorry, of course it should be local =) You can forgive me, I have a cold now ((

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all of those statements do the same thing, just to different list items. Assuming that's correct, you can do this:

```
$("ul.side-block-content li").hover(
    function(){
        var link = $(this).find(".article-title a"),
            span = link.find("span");
        span.replacewith($titleMarquee + link.text() + '</span></marquee>');
    },
    function(){
        var link = $(this).find(".article-title a"),
            marquee = link.find("marquee");
        marquee.replaceWith('<span>' + link.text() + '</span>');
    }
);
```

`hover` is a shortcut for hooking up functions to `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. Within each function, `this` will refer to the `li` element itself, and so if we wrap it in a jQuery object we can use `find` to find its descendants. It looks like you're working primarily with the contents of a link, so the code finds that link, then finds either the `span` (on `mouseenter`) or the `marquee` (on `mouseleave`) and replaces it with either a `marquee` or a `span` containing the link text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('ul.side-block-content').delegate('li', 'mouseleave', function() {
    $a = $(this).find('.article-title a');
    $a.filter('span:first').replaceWith($titleMarquee + $a.text()
                                        + '</span></marquee>');
});
```